# How to develop multilingual website in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

Hi I have developed one website using **Umbraco**. I have developed website in English. I want to make my website as multilingual. I am looking for the approaches to implement multilingual website. As i am using first time i have several questions running in my mind. I am trying to figure out below points.

1. Like **sharepoint**, has **umbraco** automatically transfer pages to other languages?
2. Should i create two root nodes(one with English and one with arabic).
3. If i use **Angularjs** i can use json files(with key/value pair)  to convert to any other language.

May I get some useful tips on the above points? Thanks. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Like sharepoint, has umbraco automatically transfer pages to other languages?

Nope, there's no automatic translating in Umbraco.

2. Should i create two root nodes(one with English and one with arabic).

This is one well known approach.

3. If i use Angularjs i can use json files(with key/value pair) to convert to any other language.

This could work. You could look into the Dictionary service which is built into Umbraco. Some of this topic is covered on [Umbraco 7 Working with languages/Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488723/umbraco-7-working-with-languages-dictionary).